# ENOTDIR npm install

Tags: node.js, npm, discord.js, npm-install

Im trying to install discord.js on my Ubuntu server, using :

```
npm install discord.js
```

But i've got the following error

```
npm ERR! Linux 4.15.0
npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "discord.js"
npm ERR! node v8.10.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.5.2
npm ERR! path /root/Minebot/node_modules/.staging/@types/ws-24e3a2dd/package.json
npm ERR! code ENOTDIR
npm ERR! errno -20
npm ERR! syscall open

npm ERR! ENOTDIR: not a directory, open '/root/Minebot/node_modules/.staging/@types/ws-24e3a2dd/package.json'
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /root/Minebot/npm-debug.log
```

Anyone can help me ?

I've update node, but i don't know what directory is missing...

Comment: as per their requirement, Node.js 16.9.0 or newer is required. you are installing it on node 8.https://www.npmjs.com/package/discord.js?activeTab=readme

Comment: @Nonik Please post your comment as an answer as I believe it may solve the OP's original issue.

Comment: OP, as clearly stated in your log, `npm ERR! node v8.10.0`. Are you sure you updated your node version? Discord.js requires node.js v16.9.0 as Nonik had stated before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as per their requirement, Node.js 16.9.0 or newer is required. you are installing it on node 8. [npmjs.com/package/discord.js?activeTab=readme](https://%20npmjs.com/package/discord.js?activeTab=readme)

Install NVM on your system  to manage node version